# Create Line Item with custom type Shopware 6

Tags: php, shopware, shopware6

I would to create a Line Item with custom type. I already created a handler for custom type and registered it in services. This is a code what I have:

`

```php
$lineItem = $this->lineItemFactoryRegistry->create([
    'type' => 'example',
    'id' => $id,
    'quantity' => 1
], $context);
$lineItem->setLabel('myLabel');
$lineItem->setRemovable(true);
$lineItem->setGood(false);
```

`

The $id variable is a random uuid.

In controller I try to add the line item like this:

`

```php
$this->cartService->add($cart, $lineItem, $context)
```

`
but after run this code I don't see my Line Item in the cart. I need to create and add the line item in controller because I want to create line item after link on my custom <a href=#"> link.

Do You have any idea where can be a problem?

I tried to add custom handler and registered it in services and I also tried to add line item via API (/store-api/checkout/cart/line-item)

Answer (score 0):

You need to persist the cart after making changes to it.

So you need to inject `Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\CartPersister` to your controller as a service.

After making changes to your `$cart` you need to persist it to the database, so your code should look something like this:

```php
$lineItem = $this->lineItemFactoryRegistry->create([
    'type' => 'example',
    'id' => $id,
    'quantity' => 1
], $context);
$lineItem->setLabel('myLabel');
$lineItem->setRemovable(true);
$lineItem->setGood(false);

$cart->add($lineItem);

$this->persister->save($cart, $saleschannelContext); // Am assuming $context is not an instance of "Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\SalesChannelContext", and if not add "Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\SalesChannelContext $saleschannelContext" to your controller action as an argument if you haven't.
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried your code and of course if I save with $this->persister->save(...) but don't refresh the checkout page, I will see 2 items in the database. After refreshing the checkout page to see one product and my custom line item, I only see 1 item in the database. It looks like I can save, but after trying to render the cart something is not right so my line item is deleted. Do you have another idea?

Comment: Update your question, but this time lets see what your controller action looks like. You can change the details but the steps should relatively be the same.

Comment: The question is still the same. I trying to create line item with custom type and add like a voucher in the cart. I have simple controller and inside it I create the Line Item, add the line item into the cart but after save (with persister) and check the checkout page I didin't see my Line Item

Comment: I had the same problem not more than 2 months ago, but I cant help if I don't have a full overview of your scenario:

1. Did you set a price definition to your line item?

```php
$definition = new \Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Price\Struct\QuantityPriceDefinition(
  0,
  $context->buildTaxRules($taxId)
);

$lineItem->setPriceDefinition($definition);

$lineItem->setPrice(
  $this->calculator->calculate($definition, $context)
);
```

Comment: Finally I used CartProcessor for that. But thank you very much for try to help me. I created line item like this https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/checkout/cart/add-cart-discounts